# product of random variables, assymetric and piecewise

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X∼U(−10,10)$ and $Y$ have a distribution that is piecewise defined as follows:

$$ f_Y(y) = \left \{ \begin{array}{ccc} \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{16y+9}} & if & -\dfrac{9}{16} < y \leq 0 \\ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{16y+9}} & if & 0 \leq y < 1 \end{array}\right.  $$

What is the distribution of $W=XY$, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

---

I will be using this integral $\displaystyle\int \dfrac{1}{|y|} f_X \left ( \dfrac{w}{y} \right) f_Y(y) dy.$

My biggest problem are the bounds, I can't seem to get them right.

I propose to separate the integrals into two: $\displaystyle\int_{-y} + \displaystyle\int_{+y}$ and will call them $A$ and $B$.

For A, we begin by saying $w > 0$. If $-10 < w/y < 0$, then $y < 0$, hence $y< -w/10$. Since $y > -9/16$, then the bounds for A should from $[-9/16, -w/10]$.

Is this right? There is no need to solve the integral. I am just asking help for the bounds. Your insights will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

- Random variable $X \sim \text{Uniform}(-10,10)$ with pdf $f(x)$:

[image]

- Random variable $Y$ has pdf $g(y)$:

[image]

We seek the pdf of the product of two independent random variables, namely $W = X Y$. This can be somewhat cumbersome to do by hand, but can be derived easily using the `TransformProduct` function in the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica*. In particular, the pdf of $W$ is given immediately as:

[image]

All done.

Here is a plot of the pdf of $W = X Y$ derived above:

[image]

**Notes**

1. One can present the result a bit more neatly, taking advantage of symmetry.
2. As disclosure, I should note that I am one of the authors of the software used.